# How to reference one column by multiple tables columns primary keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database consist of 3 tables each table indicate one user like this:

1. Admin table 'User 1'.
2. Staff table 'User 2'.
3. Student table 'user 3'.

I want to implement a common table between them called 'POST'
WHERE each user can post content to the post table content column,
however I need to Identify the type of posters ' the one who posted the post ' so I'm adding a column
user_type to the table POST
the column user_type should hold the ID of the USER ' Admin, Staff, Student '

I'm in a case where I want to be able to refer to this column ( user_type) in the POST table to multiple table columns Admin table, Staff table, Student table. So
I Can identify the USER who posted the post.

Comment: Hi, no need to SHOUT at us we all hear quite well

Comment: _Database Design Mistake_ Suggest you put all your users in one table! Add a column to indicate what type of user they are, Good DB Design, makes issues disappear

Comment: Which database type are you using? You have used multiple tags

Comment: With your design there's nothing to stop user1 existing in all 3 tables- unless you code for it, and it's not possible to have foreign key checks in post.

Comment: I'm using MySql database

Comment: You should not have three separate tables for users, just one.  There can be a type in the table.  If you need additional columns for the type, you can use ancillary tables for that specific type.

Comment: How about I implement a relation which gather all the users and the post id ? I'm not that expert in relational database design , if you can assist with a structure I really would appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

All these kind of users are persons that you need to store in one parent table called "Users" or "Persons" from which the parent's table are "User 1", "User 2", "User 3"...

This is called inheritance in data modeling.

Thus you can join the post table to the father table.

As an example :

```
CREATE TABLE T_PERSON_PRS           (PRS_ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, PRS_NAME...)
CREATE TABLE T_PERSON_ADMIN_PAM     (PRS_ID INT PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY T_PERSON_PRS (PRS_ID), ... )
CREATE TABLE T_PERSON_STAFF_PSF     (PRS_ID INT PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY T_PERSON_PRS (PRS_ID), ... )
CREATE TABLE T_PERSON_STUDENT_PSD   (PRS_ID INT PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY T_PERSON_PRS (PRS_ID), ... )
CREATE TABLE T_POST_PST             (PST_ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, PRS_ID INT PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY T_PERSON_PRS (PRS_ID), ...)
```

Comment: That's a wonderful hint , but i suspect your query is in sql , can i have the MySql version ? it's quite confusing for me to refer columns in mysql . and thanks for that mate

Comment: This is SQL SIO standard language. The only difference for MySQL is that IDENTITY must be replaced by AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: thanks , tho doesn't seems like that , INDEX MUST be identified in MySql